# How to share resources in multi module maven project

Tags: maven, slf4j, multi-module

I have a multi-module `maven` project with one root and multiple child projects. I am planning to use `SL4J` for logging. However, I have to place the `log4j.properties` in all child projects to be able to configure `log4j`.

To be able to reuse a single properties file, I tried keeping the file in `src\main\resources` directory of the root. However, `sl4j` complains that it cannot find the properties file unless it exists in each individual project.

Is it possible what I am trying to do? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The 'distributable' is responsible for the final `log4j.properties`, not every dependency is has. However, tests will probably complain about the absence of this file, so put a version of `log4j.properties` under `src/test/resources`.